# How to populate cells of matrix from a table in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have a table, created from an existing data.frame, which looks like:

```
tab <- as.table(
  matrix(c(0.625, 0.625, 0.375, 0.375, 1, 1), nrow=2, 
  dimnames=list(action = c("1", "Sum"), status = c("fail", "pass", "Sum")))
)

#      status
#action  fail  pass   Sum
#   1   0.625 0.375 1.000
#   Sum 0.625 0.375 1.000
```

I want to populate these values into a row in an array, `p1`:

```
p1 <- array(0,c(2,2,2))
colnames(p1)=c("within","out")
rownames(p1)=c("within","out")
```

So I want to get .625 and .375 from the first row of `tab` and put it into the first row of the first matrix of `p1`, to get:

```
#, , 1
#
#       within   out
#within  0.625 0.375
#out     0.000 0.000
#
#, , 2
#
#       within out
#within      0   0
#out         0   0
```

Comment: I really have no idea what you are doing here. You do realise we can't see your data?

Comment: I will  update my question.

Comment: I want to calculate the probability of success and fail from an empirical distribution and update the value of transition probability matrix of p1.

Comment: Instead of p1[1,,1]<-matrix(c(tab$p,tab$f),2,1,byrow = TRUE)
I have to set the position of each cell inside the p1 matrix. which will be 
 p1[1,,1]<-matrix(c(tab[1,1],tab[1,2]),2,1,byrow = TRUE)

Comment: I've edited and updated your question. This is what you should ultimately be aiming for when asking a question. Simplify so that only your core issue is being addressed, and provide data that anyone can run and check the results against.

Comment: Thank you so much , I am new to R programming.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be getting into a mess of code here, but you can just do:

```
p1[1,,1] <- tab["1",c("fail","pass")]
#or
p1[1,,1] <- tab[1,1:2]

#, , 1
#
#       within   out
#within  0.625 0.375
#out     0.000 0.000
#
#, , 2
#
#       within out
#within      0   0
#out         0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `p1[1,,1]<-matrix(c(tab$p,tab$f),2,1,byrow = TRUE)`
I have to set the position of each cell of a tab inside the p1 matrix. which will be

```
p1[1,,1]<-matrix(c(tab[1,1],tab[1,2]),2,1,byrow = TRUE)
```